# CLIUSR certificate expiration

Tags: exchange, cluster, certificate

I have an Exchange 2019 DAG and the CLIUSR certificate (clusinfracert) will expire soon.  I have extensively researched this and there are very few resources online that address this certificate.
There is nothing to 'try', it's either manually renew it via ECP or allow it to expire and see what happens to the DAG.

Do I need to manually renew this cert or will it renew on its own?

Comment: How about this issue now?

Answer (score 1):

The certificate 'CLIUSR' on server 'servername' is about to expire on 'date'
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eda7a791-032b-45a5-9df8-0fd5a488d0f5/the-certificate-cliusr-on-server-servername-is-about-to-expire-on-date?forum=Exch2019

yes, there is not much documentation that we could find that references a certificate issued to CLIUSR, but according to this thread, we could know:
“Windows clustering appears to self-manage these, making the Exchange ECP warnings unnecessary (and a bit scary).
So nothing to do in exchange, despite the warnings. “